# Add "total" column as a dimension in Druid queries

Tags: database, druid

Is it possible to aggregate the following dataset:

| property_name | metric_value |
| --- | --- |
| A | 20 |
| B | 40 |
| C | 40 |
| null | 100 |

Into:

| property_name | metric_value | total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 20 | 100 |
| B | 40 | 100 |
| C | 40 | 100 |

My goal is to calculate another metric based on the formula: `metric_value / total`
which I am having troubles with doing as my query is based on `groupBy` (this is must have, but I can squeeze in another subquery if needed).

The `null -> 100` is used using `subtotalSpecs` in my top level query.

The query I've built so far looks like this:

```
{
  "dataSource":
  {
    "query":
    {
      "aggregations": [{"fieldName": "duration","name": "duration","type": "longSum"}],
      "dataSource":
      {
        "condition": "customer_id == \"r.customer_id\"",
        "joinType": "LEFT",
        "left": "sessions_datasource",
        "right":
        {
          "query":
          {
            "dataSource": "demographics_datasource",
            "dimensions": ["customer_id","weight"],
            "granularity": "all",
            "intervals": ["P1M/2022-05-02"],
            "queryType": "groupBy"
          },
          "type": "query"
        },
        "rightPrefix": "r.",
        "type": "join"
      },
      "dimensions": [
        "property_name",
        {
          "dimension": "r.customer_id",
          "outputName": "customer_id",
          "outputType": "STRING",
          "type": "default"
        },
        {
          "dimension": "r.weight",
          "outputName": "weight",
          "outputType": "LONG",
          "type": "default"
        }
      ],
      "granularity": "all",
      "intervals": ["P1M/2022-05-02"],
      "queryType": "groupBy"
    },
    "type": "query"
  },
  "dimensions": ["property_name","viewing_hours"],
  "granularity": "all",
  "intervals": ["P1M/2022-05-02"],
  "queryType": "groupBy",
  "subtotalsSpec": [
    ["property_name"],
    []
  ],
  "virtualColumns": [{"expression": "weight * duration","name": "viewing_hours","outputType": "LONG","type": "expression"}]
}
```

Another idea I might have would be to create a separate query which will calculate the total value and then ingest that as a constant aggregator with pre-calculated value, but if possible I'd like to handle this in a single query